# Angular 9 : 404 error occur when refresh though browser

Tags: angular, vps

I got an 404 issue when I tried to load this URL mysite.com/menu. But when start with the homepage and choose the menu I didn't have issue.

I create an .htaccess file like it is shown in Angular documentation , but still have the issue.

My environment : 
VPS 
Os : Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Have you checked on local?

Comment: I am sorry, but in your question missing some details, you have to include at least the angular routing that should point to your page

Comment: on which http-server your app deployed?

Comment: I'm using Apache as http server

Comment: @steflight I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @Darshana Yes I found the solution I can share if you need or if you still have the issue

Comment: @steflight Yes please share the solution you found.

Comment: This is how i Configured my virtualHost . But you can do it in a .htaccess file 
RewriteEngine on
    <Directory /var/www/html/geluleciole.com>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow HTML5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of my virtual host.
You can do the same on .htaccess if you can't edit your virtual Host configuration

RewriteEngine on
<Directory /var/www/html/mysite.com>
RewriteEngine on

```
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow HTML5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</Directory>
```